# Global Vogan A-packet is infinite set?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

For an cuspidal automorphic representation of general linear group, we can attach its global Vogan A-packet.

Though I thought that it is finite set, in some paper, it is written that there are infinitely many automorphic cuspidal representations in the associated packet.

How is it possible?

Comment: What is the precise context in which it is asserted to be infinite?

Comment: @Kimball, Page 40 line 2~3 of the following paper. https://www.math.purdue.edu/~liu2053/S6.pdf

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not for a general linear group $GL_n$, but for some other reductive group -- apparently $Sp_{2(m-n)}$. (For $GL_n$ I believe all $A$-packets are finite, because they're singletons!) In general a global packet is a product of local packets, and all the local guys are finite, but since the set of places is infinite, the global packet can be infinite -- you can construct explicit examples using restriction to $SL_2$ of automorphic reps of $GL_2$ (the packet has more than one element at any unramified place where the Hecke eigenvalue is 0).

Comment: @Loeffler, Thank you for the comment. May I ask some stupid quesiton? If $\pi$ is a unitary irreducible cuspidal automorphic representation of $GL(2)$, I am wondering whether there are infinitely many places $v$ such that $\pi_v$ is discrete series representation. Because the local A-packet for $Mp(2)$ associated to $\pi_v$ is singleton iff $\pi$ is not discrete series, if such places $v$, which makes $\pi_v$ discrete series,  are infinitely many, then there are infinitely many cuspidal representations in the global Vogan A-packet for $Mp(2)$ associated to $\pi$.

Comment: @Loeffler, I think $S_{\pi}$, the set of places $v$ such that $\pi_v$ is square integrable, is finite because unramified representation can never be square-integrable. Since the number of elements of the global Vogan A-packet of $\pi$ for $Mp(2)$ is $2^{|S_{\pi}|}$, the number of global cuspidal representations in the packet seems also finite.